# KeyCloak failed verification of token: Invalid token issuer. Expected http but was https

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, keycloak, nginx-ingress

I have a Problem with KeyCloak 19.0.1 deployed in Kubernetes as custom docker image (build by me) and Spring Boot client application. I see in my app logs:

```
o.k.adapters.OAuthRequestAuthenticator   : failed verification of token: Invalid token issuer. Expected 'http://auth.example.com/realms/MyRealm', but was 'https://auth.example.com/realms/MyRealm'
```

My application is accessible via `https://example.com`, the KeyCloak is accessible via `https://auth.example.com`. All pods are behind Ingress Nginx. I set the ingress to detect correct client IP (by setting:  `controller.service.externalTrafficPolicy=Local`). If I'm trying to login to admin console with bad credentials I see in KeyCloak logs my public IP:

```
WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-68) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=dbb1ee57-XXXX, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=null, ipAddress=165.225.XX.XX, error=user_not_found, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=https://auth.example.com/admin/master/console/#/MyRealm/realm-settings/general, code_id=d905f971-5638-40e0-8460-73df72e68398, username=xxxx, authSessionParentId=d905f971-XXXX, authSessionTabId=2VFrXXXXXX
```

Also `https://auth.example.com/realms/master/.well-known/openid-configuration` returns the whole configuration and each URI uses `https://` instead of `http://`.

Configuration of KeyCloak pod (other ENVs like DB connection cutted out):

```
env:
  - name: KC_HOSTNAME
    value: "auth.example.com"    // to override default for local development, without it something else didn't work
  - name: KC_HOSTNAME_URL
    value: "https://auth.example.com"
  - name: KC_PROXY
    value: edge
```

Start arguments passed to KeyCloak container: `start-dev --http-port 8080 --http-enabled true --hostname-strict false`.

Conf of Spring Boot (comunication between spring backend and KeyCloak inside the cluster):

```
env:
  - name: KEYCLOAK_AUTHSERVERURL
  value: http://gap-got-chart-keycloak-svc:8080
```

Defaults in application.yaml:

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: http://localhost:8081
  realm: MyRealm
  resource: my-app-id
  public-client: true
  principal-attribute: preferred_username
```

Any idea what is missconfigured?

Answer (score 1):

The workaound is to use the public DNS of the KeyCloak server:

```
env:
  - name: KEYCLOAK_AUTHSERVERURL
  value: https://auth.example.com
```

Answer (score -1):

You are running Keycloak behind proxy (Nginx), so make sure your Keycloak is aware of that (+ proxy must pass correct X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, and X-Forwarded-Host HTTP headers to Keycloak):

```
KC_PROXY=edge
```

See doc https://www.keycloak.org/server/reverseproxy

Comment: There is already KC_PROXY=edge (I updated the question). What exactly do I need to enable in proxy? Now I have `externalTrafficPolicy=Local`, but it seems not enough.